# Maven Release Plugin - prepare creates tag of Snapshot version instead of release version

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

I have following project structure:

- framework

  - framework-parent-pom
  - framework-something
  - ...

In the pom.xml of framework-parent-pom I have defined following plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <branchBase>http://.../svn/REPO/branches/framework</branchBase>
        <tagBase>http://.../svn/REPO/tags/releases/framework</tagBase>
        <tagNameFormat>release-@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
        <releaseProfiles>release</releaseProfiles>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And following SCM:

```
<scm>
    <developerConnection>scm:svn:http://.../svn/REPO/trunk/framework/framework-parent-pom</developerConnection>
</scm>
```

When I run following command...

```
mvn release:prepare -DautoVersionSubmodules=true -Darguments="-DskipTests" -Dresume=false
```

...everything seems to go well.

Locally the JAR's with the release version were created and the POM's are nicely updated to the next SNAPSHOT version. Also in SVN, at first sight it seems ok. The tag has been created with all the framework projects inside it.

However, when looking at the POM's of the tag I see that they still have the **initial snapshot version** as version. This then of course causes the perform step to build the snapshot version and not the release version.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Bottom line, release works as expected but the version in tag does not have `-SNAPSHOT` suffix removed. Right?

Comment: Indeed, that's the base problem

Comment: prepare actually tags. But did you go ahead and ran `mvn release:perform` too?

Comment: yes and that one checks out the tag with the snapshot versions and (surprisingly with no errors) installs it on my local repo (but the snapshot version). In framework-parent-pom/checkout (where Maven checks out the tag) I also see nothing but SNAPSHOT versions). What do you mean with 'prepare actually tags'?

Comment: I release this may not be tooo helpful, but I had a lot of issues with the release plugin not doing what it was supposed to do (see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16593822/maven-releaseperform-overwriting-first-ever-release-for-every-subsequent-releas)) so perhaps consider saving yourself some time and implementing it yourself. the maven scm plugin gives you a lot of the functionality you need.

Comment: Thanks, in a previous project we abandoned the release plugin and just did it with custom scripts. I was hoping, a few years down the road, it would have become easier.

Comment: I worked with the release plugin with SVN and GIT mainly using hierarchical projects. I had a few issues in the beginning but since then I strongly recommend using it. To me it seems you may trick the release plugin with the structure. Is the release executed in your framework-parent-pom folder or its parent? With a flat directory layout (or a one that sort of is a bit of both, I guess you put it like this because of the IDE?) you need to play with the base url of the developer connection so all folders are used in the tag. Does the SVN history of the tag tell you something?

Comment: The structure is indeed because we use eclipse so I agree that may be related to the problem. We have abandoned the plugin (for now at least) and replaced it with something customized (which in the end is faster, more flexible and does more) so I'm not able to recheck for now.

Answer (score 9):

I find the workaround in the maven-release-plugin issue tracker [MRELEASE-812](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MRELEASE-812) :

In my case the change was :

```
       <plugin>
         <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
-        <version>2.2.2</version>
+        <version>2.4.1</version>
         <configuration>
           <releaseProfiles>release</releaseProfiles>
           <goals>install animal-sniffer:check deploy site</goals>
         </configuration>
+        <dependencies>
+          <dependency>
+            <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>
+            <artifactId>maven-scm-api</artifactId>
+            <version>1.8.1</version>
+          </dependency>
+          <dependency>
+            <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>
+            <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-gitexe</artifactId>
+            <version>1.8.1</version>
+          </dependency>
+        </dependencies>
       </plugin>
```

Comment: +1 the thread you linked to was indeed the fix for me too. Spot on.

Comment: I ran into this problem with maven-release-plugin 2.5.  I then tried your suggestion.  I then, per @Tristan, looked at SCM-740.  Which says it's fixed in SCM 1.9.1.  release plugin 2.5.0 is SCM 1.9.  So, it is still yet to be resolved in maven release plugin.  I think it will be fixed once this issue is resolved: https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MRELEASE-888.  I was able to get it to work by using your pom snippet and replacing the 1.8.1 versions with 1.9.1

Comment: As expected, it also works with release plugin 2.5, scm plugin 1.9.1 (or 1.9.2).   The key is SCM 1.9.1 or greater.

Comment: Does not apply to new Maven versions (3.6.3 and later)

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem to this.  It was tagging the snapshot version because it wasn't committing the POM change before tagging.

I found it would only work if I used the following configuration options:

```
<remoteTagging>false</remoteTagging>
<suppressCommitBeforeTag>false</suppressCommitBeforeTag>
```

Answer (score 4):

I was also facing same issue. In my came it was because of wrong SCM developerConnection string.

```
<scm>
<developerConnection>scm:svn:http://.../../trunk</developerConnection>
</scm>
```

I have ckeckout the code from **Branch** and was executing  **release:prepare**.

you can check your developerConnection path, It should same as your code repository path.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running into this problem you are most likely experiencing https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MRELEASE-812 and will need to change version of the release plugin (or git) that you use.

HTH,
Jan

Answer (score 2):

This problem is still unresolved for complex project structure.

See here for patch preview :
http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SCM-740

Answer (score 2):

If you are seeing this error with version 2.5 of the maven release plugin then you could be experiencing this bug: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MRELEASE-875

If your top level pom.xml is not in the git root then `release:prepare` does not commit the pom before tagging.

The only work around seems to be to rearrange your project structure in git.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem when cutting my first release (which was really messy).
The second time this problem vanished - so just do a second (clean/fresh) release.

Comment: hm - wired - unsure if the `<tagNameFormat>` interferes somehow - did you try without?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I circumvented the problem by manually editing the tag's POM to set it to the released version. Then the release:perform at least works.

But it's a weird problem that I don't have a clue about where it's coming from.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you can also `git config --global status.displayCommentPrefix true` to output in the old format so that maven can parse the `git status` command.

Answer (score 1):

just for the records, the only workaround that worked for me was the workaround of Andreas Dangel of adding a git config to set the old behavior of parsing localized git output, the command is this one

```
git config --add status.displayCommentPrefix true
```

here is the explanation of the workaround: [http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SCM-740?focusedCommentId=341325&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-341325](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SCM-740?focusedCommentId=341325&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-341325)

one last hint, this workaround works only for version 2.4.2, I tested with 2.5 and it does not work

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved with the combination of Maven 3.2.2 and Maven Release Plugin 2.5.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I managed the release plugin to work for me. I wrote the following script. Hopefully it will help someone.

```
# Reads release.properties and extracts properties by key
function prop {
    grep -E "${1}=" ./release.properties|cut -d'=' -f2
}

echo "Performing a release [Dry run]..."    
mvn release:clean release:prepare -DautoVersionSubmodules=true --offline -DdryRun=true

TAG_NAME=$(prop 'scm.tag')

echo "Tagging a release $TAG_NAME..."   
find .. -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -name "*pom.xml.tag" -exec rename -f 's/\.tag$//' {} ";"
find .. -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -name "*pom.xml" -exec git add {} ";"
git commit -m "Release $TAG_NAME"
git tag -a -m "Release $TAG_NAME" $TAG_NAME

DEV_VERSION=$(prop 'project.dev.cp\\:cp-builder')
echo "Creating next development version $TAG_NAME..."
find .. -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -name "*pom.xml.next" -exec rename -f 's/\.next$//' {} ";"
find .. -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -name "*pom.xml" -exec git add {} ";"
git commit -m "Development version $DEV_VERSION"

echo "Pushing changes to GitLab..."
git push --follow-tags
echo "Deploying a release $TAG_NAME..."
mvn release:perform
echo "Cleaning release..."
mvn release:clean
```