# Maven release plugin is publishing to SNAPSHOT Repo rather that release repo

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, pom.xml, nexus

I just switched from svn to git, and for some reason release:prepare release:perform is not commiting to my nexus release repo, and is instead going to my snapshot repo. I've read that this is a bug in maven release plugin 2.5 but I am using 2.5.1. My pom file for the maven release plugin looks like this:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-gitexe</artifactId>
                    <version>1.9.5</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scm-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.1</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <configuration>
                <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
                <remoteTagging>false</remoteTagging>
```

I've done everything I can find to resolve this and have had no luck... This is in my parent POM, and I've exhausted my options... Any help is appreciated.

Edit: Seems its the release:prepare step that keeps adding the -SNAPSHOT on the end of the build

```
DdevelopmentVersion=test111-RC5-SNAPSHOT -DreleaseVersion=test111-RC4 -Dresume=false -DdryRun=true release:prepare
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
```

Then immediately adds it after it checks out...

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building . test111-RC4-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-release-plugin:2.4.2:prepare (default-cli) @ . ---
```

Comment: First thing would be to update to version 3.0.1.

Comment: I will try this and see if it makes a difference

Comment: I have an api incompatibility with this version.  According to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRELEASE-875 This was fixed after 2.5. I have a parent pom thats not in the git root. Maybe that has to do with it. However, still very strange behavior.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18993429/13342448 This was the fix to my issue, hopefully it saves someone more time that it took me.